play Console issue showing All AppsUpdate com.google.android.play
com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.10.3:
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14. Update to the latest Play Core library version dependency to avoid app crashes: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration
You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.
Affected app bundles and APKs:
version: 16 (3.4.6), release: 16 (3.4.6)
If you have questions about this SDK, contact the SDK provider.

what is your question

Does this answer your question? (SDK issues) com.google.android.play:core has added this note for core:1.9.0

If after performing the documentation migration there are compilation problems:
com.google.android.play:core might be a transitive dependency in your project, causing the conflict. To identify which dependency is using it, go to the android folder.
android cd

and run the following command
./gradlew app:dependencies > dependencies.txt

It will generate a text file, where you can see which dependency is using com.google.android.play:core.
In our case, it was a package that used the in_app_update package. So, we just overwrote the dependency in pubspec.
dependency_overrides:
 in_app_update: ^4.2.3

